# What type of suspension is a “suspension for cool down”?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I have recently seen two users, one on Stack Overflow and another on Meta Stack Exchange, suspended for cooling down. I want to know what type of suspension it is and what are the indications of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: No I have already visited that I need to know what is the definition for "cooling down"?

Comment: To become less angry or excited.

Comment: When I have difficulties with English expressions, it sometimes helps me to search the expression I'm having difficulties with in a search engine. It's usually easy to find a definition.

Comment: You are really misunderstanding it. I want to know what is "suspension for cooling down". The English meaning is clear to me, I want to know what type of suspension it is and what are the indications of it. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Someone gets angry or too excited. Then they are suspended so hopefully during the suspension time they can become less angry or excited, by virtue of forcefully disengaging from whatever was making them angry or excited. I'm sorry but I'm not able to help you any further.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes a user gets very emotional, angry if you wish.

If, after a moderator having asked them, talked to them, warned them, reprimanded to stop or change their behavior or actions, they show no sign to have understood what is being requested it is time to let them cool off.  Give them time to get out of their emotional state and reflect on what they have been doing.

Examples are users that start deleting all their posts, or defacing their post, be rude in posts or comments or chat.

There is nothing more to it, really.

Comment: Thanks for posting a reasonable answer. I was starting to get excitable myself.

Comment: @yivi it are excitable times ...